# how to implement custom routes in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I've got a route:

```
.state('home.blog', {
  url: "/blog",
  templateUrl: "blog.html",
  controller: "BlogController"
})
```

And my route is `localhost:3000/home/blog` I would like to change it to `localhost:3000/blog`. I searched the Internet but I have not found any simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the url part is dervied from parent. But we can explicitly set, that parent should not be used by '**^**':

```
.state('home.blog', {
  url: "^/blog",
  templateUrl: "blog.html",
  controller: "BlogController"
})
```

See the doc

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '^/list',
     ...
  });
```

Comment: Great to see that Jakub! Enjoy awesome UI-Router ;)